# Send real time messages from another activity

Tags: java, android, andengine, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am using the Google Play Game Services for my real-time multiplayer game, but I am not able to broadcast real-time messages from another activity that does not extends com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.

My activity (MainActivity) that extends the BaseGameActivity got a static instance, that I use from my other activity (RaceActivity) that uses Andengine. At first, I instanciate my MainActivity and I start the RaceActivity when all players are ready. Then, in my RaceActivity, I call a static function from my MainActivity that broadcast a message but it gives me this exception :

```
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to send message, real-time match service is not connected.
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bm$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bj.sendReliableRealTimeMessage(Unknown Source)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient.sendReliableRealTimeMessage(Unknown Source)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.MainActivity.broadcastMessage(MainActivity.java:371)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.GameScene.readyUp(GameScene.java:95)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:42)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:39)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:25)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at com.game.superninjarun.structure.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:109)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:98)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:597)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:585)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
06-02 14:55:04.585: E/AndroidRuntime(7961):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

Does someone knows what the hell is the real-time match service? I can't even find it on google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to merge both BaseGameActivity from Andengine and Google's BaseGameUtils thanks to this [post on the andengine forum](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post51410.html?hilit=google%20play%20game%20services#p51410).

I guess that the features of the GamesClient class can only be used within the Acvitity that declared it...